# django-crispy-forms : help_text_inline of FormHelper not working as expected

Tags: django-crispy-forms

For the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=110, help_text="Some sample help text.")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

And the following modelform:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-myModelForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_action = 'my_model_form_url'
        self.helper.form_error_title = 'Form Errors'
        self.helper.help_text_inline = True
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Using the following template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

The **help_text** defined in the model does not get rendered at all. It does get rendered if I change to `self.helper.help_text_inline = False` instead of `self.helper.help_text_inline = True`, but that's not what I want.

How do I get the help_text to show with `self.helper.help_text_inline = True`?

The base.html is all proper with bootstrap files all included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `help_text_inline` and `error_text_inline` cannot be set to the same value in order to work. If you set `help_text_inline` to `True`, you need to set `error_text_inline` to `False`. If you don't do it, help text messages are not displayed, in order to show form errors in case they happen.

I hadn't thought about this in detail until now. So probably the best would be to add a logging warning, telling the user to be careful with this. Maybe automatically overriding the default behavior of the other flag, in case one is set. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: The way I see it, displaying help_text inline is the primary need, and thus the 'rule'. Displaying error_text inline happens conditionally, and is thus the 'exception'. So when both help_text_inline and error_text_inline are set to True, then help_text_inline should take precedence and then any errors should be displayed below the widget (in block format).

Comment: I've fixed this in version 1.2.1 which has been released 2012/11/28 See https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/117