# ValidationError not showing in template (although field validation errors are)

Tags: django, validationerror

I am trying to raise ValidationError if a duplicate entry found in an inlineformset, just like in the docs:  [Custom formset validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) I'm using a debugging tool and stepping through the code. It successfully reaches the line: `raise ValidationError("Check Duplicate Entry")`, and subsequently, in the view it takes the else statement instead proceeding with `if formset.is_valid`. I print(formset.non_form_errors) just as in the docs. However, the example in the docs returns a list at this stage with the error message inside it. In my case, I get `<bound method BaseFormSet.non_form_errors of <django.forms.formsets.MyInlineFormSet object at 0x7fcc22e89610>>`  The template renders with the form data but the validation error does not appear to say what is wrong. I'm missing something for sure. Any help appreciated.

```
class MyInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False

    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        mylist = []
        for form in self.forms:
            myfield_data = form.cleaned_data.get("myfield")
            if myfield_data in mylist:
                raise ValidationError("Check Duplicate Entry")
            mylist.append(myfield_data)
```

My tempate just has this:

```
{% block content %}
<section class="container-fluid">
    {% crispy form %}
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

Side Note: Any field validation errors against specific fields do show up. But there I am writing the errors like so:  `self._errors["fieldname"] = self.error_class(["Error in field, please double check"])` Not sure why raise ValidationError is not working for the formset

Comment: Note that your clean method will only run if there are no other errors in the rest of the forms in your formset. That is what the `if any(self.errors): return` is doing. Can you confirm it is the case that there are no other erros.

Comment: Yes becasue I am using the debug tool in VSCode and it steps through those lines one by one so i can see which lines it is running. I may update my code with the view

Comment: so when you step through whilst debugging, the ValidationError is raised, but it's not shown on the form?

Comment: yes, could you add the view. That would be useful.

Comment: Yes it reaches the raise ValidationError line which cause it to re-render the form but the validation error doesnt show. I just saw this which seems a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094974/rendering-field-errors-in-django-crispy-forms-with-inline-forms. The solution suggest sending form errors in the context but I am using classed based views

Comment: That need not be a problem. You can still access the errors in the template just using `form.errors`.

Comment: But adding the view to the question will help come to the best solution

Comment: like this? {{ form.errors }}?

Comment: Not quite, I think `form.errors` will actually be a dict with lots of errors inside, so you would need to iterate over it. However, I think the errors should be showing without manually adding them in, so it's worth finding out why they're not displaying

Comment: Tim, I updated with my view. It's quite long so I hope you're not put off and the formsets are all defined in forms.py. If i do need to send form.errora in the context, The context it defined in get_context_data() so would heve tp pass it there unlike just assigning in that SO example

Comment: It looks like in your template you should have `{% crispy passenger_formset %}` to display the formset correctly. This should list all the errors automatically.

Comment: The formset is just part of a bigger form so the 'crispy form' refers to the whole form including the formset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! My formset is a crsipy form within a crispy form. The overall form is rendered in the template linked to the view. But I should have mentioned, I have a separate template containing the markup for the formset.

```
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-7">
       {{ formset.management_form | crispy }}
        {% for form in formset.forms %}
            <h3>Form {{forloop.counter}}</h3>
            {% crispy form %}
        {% endfor %}
       </div>
       <br>
   </div>
```

So I just needed to add `{{ formset.non_form_errors }}` below formset.management_form.